# android, scroll HorizontalScrollView to end in ListView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm using a `right-to-left` language in my `ListView` and because it's `TextView` may need more space, I used `HorizontalScrollView`. The text should be right align and when the user scrolls down, `HorizontalScrollView` should scroll to the rightest position (and as you know `HorizontalScrollView` is stuck in the leftest position at default).
this is my  `ListView` row  code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hs1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
                style="@style/text_black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

and I use the code below in `getView` of my `ListView` `Adapter` for scrolling to right but it doesn't work:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    viewHolder.hs1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    viewHolder.hs2.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                }
            },500);
```

and at last, I used `new Handler().post()` too and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, absolutely at my view when I wanted my `HorizontalScrollView` to show rtl (right-to-left) textView, The soluion is using RelativeLayout as parent .

Comment: What's the solution @Ali Aqa I'm facing the same issue with Horizontal Scroll View inside a ListView. It automatically goes to the left when I scroll the list. Can you post some code? In my layout, RelativeLayout is the parent too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use "pagescoll" to goto the next focusable (see the documentation). Hope it helps.....

Replace:

```
viewHolder.hs1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
viewHolder.hs2.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```

With:

```
viewHolder.hs1.pageScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
viewHolder.hs2.pageScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
```